# Obtain Bacula status in parseable format

Tags: bacula, parsing

Is it possible to obtain the status of Bacula Director in some parseable format?
It looks like the human-readable representation (one you can see when using bacula-console) is formed on the director side during the TCP control connection.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for in this? I get quite a lot of different things from the status command for director: runtime, memory usage, # jobs run, and lists of scheduled, running, and terminated jobs.

Comment: @DerfK I want to obtain *everything* 'status director' returns and format a nice webpage from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just written a bash scripty thing to poll the bacula client status, and write the tape write speed (in GB/hr) to a logfile, along with a datestamp:

Here's how.

```
while `/bin/true`; 
do 
  echo -n `date +%s` >> /var/log/backupspeed.log; 
  echo -n " " >> /var/log/backupspeed.log; 
  BPS=$(echo "status client"|bconsole|awk '/Bytes\/sec/ {print $3}'|cut -d'=' -f2|sed 's/,//g'); 
  echo "scale=10;($BPS/(1024^3))*(60^2)"|bc >> /var/log/backupspeed.log; 
  sleep 10; 
  echo `date +%s`; 
done
```

This is just what I threw together, to scratch my own itch, but it's pretty versatile.. You can pretty much just squirt stuff at bconsole, and parse the output.